# Any good book recommendations on discrete fractional calculus?

Tags: calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation, fractional-calculus

I am a math undergraduate student. Im interested in discrete fractional calculus topic, specifically about discrete fractional systems.

Does anyone knows some book recommendations on the topic?

P.S. I know that there's already someone asked about recommendation on fractional calculus books right [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2212783/1274067), but the books that recommended are not about the discrete one.

Thank you!